# how to set style through javascript in IE immediately

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

recently I've encountered a problem with IE. I have a function

```
function() {
    ShowProgress();
    DoSomeWork();
    HideProgress();
}
```

where ShowProgress and HideProgress just manipulate the 'display' CSS style using jQuery's css() method.

In FF everything is OK, and at the same time I change the display property to block, progress-bar appears. But not in IE. In IE the style is applied, once I leave the function. Which means it's never shown, because at the end of the function I simply hide it. (if I remove the HideProgress line, the progress-bar appears right after finishing executing the function (more precisely, immediately when the calling functions ends - and so there's nothing else going on in IE)).

Has anybody encountered this behavior? Is there a way to get IE to apply the style immediately?

I've prepared a solution but it would take me some time to implement it. My DoSomeWork() method is doing some AJAX calls, and these are right now synchronous. I assume that making them asynchronous will kind of solve the problem, but I have to redesign the code a bit, so finding a solution just for applying the style immediately would much simplier.

Thanks rezna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronous requests block the entire UI, which is horrible. You are right in your assumption, but if you want to continue down this path to the inner circles of $hell, try this:

```
function () {
    ShowProgress();
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        DoSomeWork();
        HideProgress();
    }, 0);
}
```

Note that I have not tested this. Try playing with the time-out value (currently `0`) if you still do not see anything.

Comment: yeah I thought so. playing with setTimeout is quite tricky and I think it will bring in some even worse problems.

so I'm going to redesign the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Try throwing the HideProgress method into a setTimeout. For example:

```
function() {
    ShowProgress();
    DoSomeWork();
    setTimeout(HideProgress,0);
}
```

Even though the delay is supposedly 0 milliseconds, this will have the net effect of throwing the HideProcess method to the end of the queue and may give the browser the breathing room it needs.

[Edit] I should have mentioned that this method does have a drawback if you invoke this method very often and rapidly: a race condition. You could end up with a previous timeout executing while another DoSomeWork() is executing. This *will* happen if DoSomeWork take a very long time to finish. If this is a risk, you may want to implement a counter for your progress bar and only execute HideProgress if the counter that started it is the same as the counter's present value.

Comment: the problem is not the HideProgress, but the face that during execution of DoSomeWork() the progress-bar is not visible...

Comment: If you remove `HideProgress()` and/or `DoSomeWork()` does the progress bar show up at all? Can you post your ShowProgress function?

Comment: it's written in the original question:
(if I remove the HideProgress line, the progress-bar appears right after finishing executing the function (more precisely, immediately when the calling functions ends - and so there's nothing else going on in IE)).

my ShowProgress() is simple

function ShowProgress() {
    $('#my-id').css('display', 'block');
}

Comment: Wow.  I've never seen IE behave that way. One last idea: rather than applying the style through jQuery, try applying it directly. I'm not saying that you should deploy it this way, but rather to see where the problem lies. `function ShowProgress() {document.getElementById('my-id').style.display='block'}`.

Comment: Nope, still the same. The style is visually applied after leaving the code-block.

Comment: It must be the synchronous request then. The style change is likely deferred, but then gets blocked by the request. That's really disappointing. Janmoesen's idea of throwing DoSomeWork into a timeout might work then. But I honestly don't know. Sorry.